# How to handle arrays and objects - Swift Cordova Plugin Development

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, cordova, swift2

I'm new to cordova plugin development. I'd like to implement a cordova plugin **using swift** which accepts an array, that contains objects.

For example (JavaScript):

```
var people = [{name: "joe"}, {name: "petra", age: 21}, {name: "malcolm"}];
// Actually call the plugin:
MyPlugin.doSomeStuff(people);
```

Sadly I only found [this source](http://moduscreate.com/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-for-ios/) containing information on how to implement cordova plugins using swift.
So I do know how to create a plugin, and how to transmit a string to the plugin. But how do you handle arrays and objects on the swift side coming from JavaScript?

**Sidenote: Objective-C is NOT an option for me. Please do not offer any Objective-C solutions. Thank you!**

Comment: Didn't try, but I would assume that JS arrays and dicts are bridged as NSArray's and NSDictionary's. So in your doSomeStuff method, can't you just do a `let people = command.arguments[0] as? NSArray`?

Comment: @hnh I'm gonna try this. Thank you for your guess.